# adobe reader could not open pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged

Tags: pdf, itext, sendmail

I am using iTextSharp for creating PDF for reports & send as attachment(). Pdf is created successfully & can be opened locally using Adobe Reader but can't opened after sent to mail & gives error :
"adobe reader could not open pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged "

Also pdf file size is zero in attachement.
I think its corrupted in between. what's may be the issue?

Comment: 2 things come to my mind: your creating app exited before everything was sent or the temp-pdf-file was deleted before it could be sent. OR a virus-scanner deleted the attachment on the client-side. You should check the outbox first.

Comment: Yes, eventviewer shows Symantec is blocking remote debugging sometimes but not every time. Moreover pdf is created & exists on location where we pick for mailing and attachement of type .xls, .csv is delivered without being corrupted & also a pdf file is sent as a attachment but corrupted. I feel virus scanner is not deleting attachement because files(xls, csv & pdf) are delivered, only pdf is corrupted.

Comment: @Pranav - In the OP you said "_Also pdf file size is zero in attachement_". But in your comment above you imply differently. Is the PDF attachment 1. zero bytes, or 2. greater than zero bytes, but corrupted?

Comment: @kuujinbo, Yes file size is zero in attachment & on opening with adobe reader after downloading from e-mail says file is corrupted. Problem is not with iTextSharp since file is generated with no problem. Same window service when installed on my colleague's m/c gives no problem & e-mail with proper reports are sent. :( I am unable to debug on my machine. Furthermore I am intrested in finding what is blocking service from sending email attachements from my machine.

Comment: @Pranav - The reason I asked if the file attachment is zero bytes is because if that's true, how do you know the problem is **not** with iTextSharp? Not saying it is or isn't, only that if a zero byte PDF **is** being, sent, what @ ralf.w said **may** be true - virus scanner or other client-side software may be causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with Network Security(smtp permissions) rather any programming challenge. Got permissions for SMTP & configure it. Bingo, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had with the export to PDF format, was that my file was that I had some bad HTML tags closed, please check.